# Zero bytes files

Tags: java

When try to download multiple file from url with different queries using threads files are not properly written or producing 0 byte files or some of the files do no open. The code is given below. Please help me guys...

```
public void run() {

    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (code == 400) {
            LOGGER.info("Response Status:" + strUrl);
        } else if (code == 302 || code == 304) {
            LOGGER.info("Redirected 302: " + strUrl);
            String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
            newUrl = newUrl.replace(".html", "");


            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            URL website = new URL(newUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > -1)
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            fos.close();
            is.close();

        } else {
            LOGGER.error(conn.getResponseCode() + ":  " + strUrl);
        }
    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Connection Time out " + strUrl);
        System.out.println("Connection Time out " + strUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Check the return code from your redirected connection. It's probably not what you expect.

Comment: What log messages are you getting.  I can think of lots of reasons why you might be getting zero length files ... or nothing at all.  The log messages and other output will tell you a lot.

Comment: By the way, combining writing stuff to standard output with logging is a bad idea.

Comment: strUrl is the query url and it is redirected to another URL to download a pdf file. Upto InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); is working fine. But the writing part gives the problem.